# How to prevent undelivered promise from hanging?

Tags: concurrency, clojure

Here is an example from clojure for the brave and true:

```
(time
 (let [butter-promise (promise)]
   (doseq [butter [yak-butter-international butter-than-nothing baby-got-yak]]
     (future (if-let [satisfactory-butter (satisfactory? (mock-api-call butter))]
               (deliver butter-promise satisfactory-butter))))
   (println "And the winner is:" @butter-promise)))
```

What if none of the butter products satisfy our criteria?

Answer (score 3):

```
(let [butter-promise (promise)]
  ;; ...
  (if-let [winner (deref butter-promise 10000 nil)]
    (println "And the winner is:" winner)
    (println "Butter timed out."))
```